# returning value of checkbox

Tags: php, jquery, html

im trying to return the value of my checkboxes can you help me bec still i cant return the value if the value is 1 i hope there will be a check in my checkbox

here is my code:

```
    <input  type="hidden" name="stud_no[]" value="<?php echo $row['student_no'];?>">


    <input  type="text" name="prelim[]" value="<?php echo $row['prelim_pts']?>"  id="prelim_<?php echo $row['student_no'];?>" class="txtprelim" ></td>
    <td><input  type="text" name="midterm[]" value="<?php echo $row['midterm_pts']?>"  id="midterm_<?php echo $row['student_no'];?>" class="txtmidterm" ></td>
    <td> <input  type="text" name="final[]" value="<?php echo $row['finals_pts']?>" id="final_<?php echo $row['student_no'];?>" class="txtfinal" ></td>

<td>

<input type="text" name="average[]" id="average_<?php echo $row['student_no']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['average_pts']; ?>"  readonly="readonly"> 

</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="disable[]" id="able" value="<?php echo $row['disable_comp'];?>" class="dis"> </td>

<?php

    echo "</tr>";
    }
}

    ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="sec_no" value="<?php echo $_GET["section_no"]; ?>" />
    <input type="submit" value="UPDATE">
    </form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    //var bIsFirebugReady = (!!window.console && !!window.console.log);

    $(document).ready(function(){

        p="";
        m="";
        f="";

 var computeValues = function(){
            var id = $(this).attr("id").replace("prelim_", "").replace("midterm_", "").replace("final_", "");
            p = $("#prelim_" + id).val();
            m = $("#midterm_" + id).val();
            f = $("#final_" + id).val();
            Compute(p, m, f, id);
        };

        $("input").bind('keyup', computeValues);

        function Compute(p, m, f, studno) {
            var average;
            average = parseFloat(p * 0.3) + parseFloat(m * 0.3) + parseFloat(f * 0.4);
            $("#average_" + studno).val(average.toFixed());     
        }

        $(".dis").change(function() {
            var val = $(this).val();
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                var checked = $('input[type=checkbox]').is(':checked');
                $("input").unbind('keyup', computeValues);




            }
             else {
                $("input").bind('keyup', computeValues).trigger('keyup');

            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: If you can define your problem description in two or three lines instead of one, It will be more easy to understand for us what the actual problem was  (without analyzing code first )

Comment: can you include the html of you checkboxes???

Comment: ok wait ill edit it with html checkboxes

Comment: Please clear this out?? You want to show check/unchecked based upon what you php script returns???

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var checked=$("#chkboxid").is(':checked');
```

`checked` will contain either true or false

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = $(this).prop('checked');
```